# Parse variable in the Query SSIS

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008

In SQL Task Editor I have the following Query

```
DELETE FROM 
[TICKETS_DATA]
where BILLING_TICKETS_DATA_Time_ID < 
(SELECT TIME_ID
FROM [TIME]
WHERE (TIME_Year = ?)  AND (TIME_Month = ?)) - 1
```

I have `TIME_ID` with relevant Month and Year present in the row.
I have 2 Variables present as `Time_Month` (int32) and `Time_Year` (int32) for eg 08 and 2012 respectively.

I want to pick up the Current `Time_ID` and pass the above query in SQL Task Editor.

Currently in the Table I was storing 1 month of data and now want to store 3 months data.

Kindly, assist me in Parameter mapping and how to parse the variable in the SQL Command query.

Comment: Your question is a bit confused, but as far as I can tell you want to modify this query so that any data older than 3 months is removed. Is this the case? If so this query won't do it because nothing will be deleted in January, February and March. Can you tell us the full structure of [TICKETS_DATA], esp if there's a DateTime column for the dimension.

Comment: What is the format of time_id?  Depending upon the value, you may be able to simply change the -1 to -3 assuming that the time table has one entry per month and a serial number assigned for the time_id column.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Time_id in the table is a numeric value that is incremented by one for each record, and there is as stated one record per year/month combo and the numbers increase sequentially, by one each time, in date order (i.e. 2000 01 has time_id 1 and 2000 02 has time_id 2 and 2001 1 has time_id 13), then you can just change the -1 to -3 to delete records from your table that are older than three months.  Bear in mind that since this was probably run last month, you will have two months in the table on the first run after this change and it will delete 0 records in this first run.  Next run, you will have 3 months and it will delete 0 records again.  On the third run (assuming it is only run once a month) you will have three months of data and it will delete records from 4 months prior to that date.